# Shutdown a remote system?

Tags: c#, networking, shutdown

How would I go about shutting down or rebooting a remote system.

A scenario can be used as a group of networked computers in a school room, the teacher will be able to shutdown selected systems to shutdown from their machine.

How would I be able to do this.

I have searched for a method to retrieve networked machines, but in the scenario how would this work?

Comment: How could you display networking computers on a LAN  ?

Comment: There is a class to display the name of the systems in the network, I can then iterate through each computer and shut them down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft SysInternals utility [`psShutdown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) will do exactly what you're looking for.

> You can use PsShutdown to initiate a shutdown of the local or a remote computer, logoff a user, lock a system, or to abort an imminent shutdown.

Comment: PsShutdown is exactly what I'm looking for. Works great. Wouldn't mind looking for an inbuilt method but this would do.

Answer (score 1):

Using the shutdown.exe from the command line in Windows would work, you can specify the computer name you'd like to shutdown and plenty of other options.. you could put shortcuts to these commands on the user's desktop so it would be easy for him/her to shutdown each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Win32_OperatingSystem.Shutdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/shutdown-method-in-class-win32-operatingsystem) method.